# Set localhost time to protractor

Tags: javascript, selenium, protractor

i want run my protractor tests in locahost time.
I tried to modify my config.js like this

```
capabilities: {
'browserName': 'firefox',
  'time-zone': 'local',
```

but it didn't resolve my problem. 
What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

I think that `local` not working for time-zone, better to use the time-zone of your location, such as: `'time-zone': 'Alaska'`. Consult here for more locations https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones

Comment: Thanks, it is a way. But  assertion  of my autotest depends from current time. And if i will change run machine with other timezone in setting-test wiil fail

Comment: And using the Date() of javascript. It returns this: Tue Jun 27 2017 10:39:34 GMT-0300 (Official time of Brazil) for me that I'm in Brazil. It's work ? Read more: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_dates.asp